# why css3 media query doesn't work?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use media query in css3 to make my website responsive, it's seems I did all right but it doesn't work, here's my code:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
body{
  background-color: blue;
}
}
}
body {
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
}
```

and the header:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

the css file work, but all the media querys doesn't...

Comment: You have one extra curly brace } in code. Also, write general css first and then at bottom of that write media query. Ordering is important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS styles are prioritised by many things, order is one of them. Also, there was one extra `}`.

```
body {
    background-color: #fcfcfc;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    body {
        background-color: blue;
    }
}
```

and the header

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

Comment: thx @jackallen ! do you know what's the standart media queries breakpoints?

Answer (score 2):

See [the cascading order](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascading-order).

> Sort according to importance (normal or important)

Both rules are normal

> and origin

Both are author rules

> Sort rules with the same importance and origin by specificity of selector

`body` and `body` are identical selectors, so have equal specificity.

> Finally, sort by order specified: if two declarations have the same weight, origin and specificity, the latter specified wins.

The `background-color: #fcfcfc;` rules comes after `background-color: blue;` so it overwrites it.

**Order** is important. Reverse the order of the rules.

(You also have an extra `}` which causes a syntax error. Remove it.)

```css
body {
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  body {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code should work.

```
body {
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    body{
      background-color: blue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have too many closing tags and media queries must run after your general styling. 
https://jsfiddle.net/o8qcuyzb/

```css
body {
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
body{
  background-color: blue;
}
}
```

```html
<body></body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it does not work is given correctly and in detail by Quentin. 
It is because the order is important in CSS.

If you say set a property for the same element twice in a CSS file, then one that comes later is applied. So if you have,

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
 body { background-color: white; }
}

body { background-color: red; }
```

in the same file, the `body` tag will inherit the `red` background-color (even for screen sizes < 480px). Just putting the media query after will solve the issue.

Another work around I use in media queries is to include the `!important` rule.
SO, in the following case, `body` tag will have `white` background-color for screen sizes < 480px and `red` background-color otherwise.

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
 body { background-color: white !important; }
}

body { background-color: red; }
```

So, when it comes to **media queries** I find it useful to enforce the property using `!important` rule so that I don't have to worry about the order, as often the media queries are added later on. But it is not a good practice, so use judiciously as it makes further debugging difficult.

Also, remove that extra closing curly bracket `}`!

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't add meta viewport tag, Check your Html file.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```